# How to remove a group of element and leave one with jQuery or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a goup of element (Whatever the number of this element)
and i want to remove all and leave one 
with javascript or jQuery

For example :

This is what i have :

```
<li>
  <div class='x'/>
  <div class='x'/>
  <div class='x'/>
  <div class='x'/>
  <div class='x'/>
  ...
</li>
```

I want to make it like this

```
<li>
 <div class='x'/>
</li>
```

Comment: i tried to use the ranking of the element :first :last ...
and remove()
but this isn't useful

Comment: Quite simple: `$("li > div.x:gt(0)").remove();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way you are removing every element that has a class x except for the last one.

`$(".x:not(:last)").remove();`

Answer (score 2):

You can use slice which is intended exactly for your purpose. 
https://api.jquery.com/slice/
It basically creates a subset out of the set of elements.

```
$("li .x").slice(1).remove();
```

This examples selects all elements except the first one and removes that subset